# Problems trying casting

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I've a class that extends TextField. This class transform the text to uppercase and now I'm trying do a casting with this class using BeanFieldGroup but doesn't work.
Using TextField works, but with my class that extends TextField doesn't.

```
/** class transfor text to uppercase */
public class TextUpper extends TextField implements TextChangeListener{

    public TextUpper(Integer length){
        super();
        setMaxLength(length);   
        setImmediate(true);
        setTextChangeEventMode(TextChangeEventMode.EAGER);
        addTextChangeListener(this);
    }

    public TextUpper(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void textChange(TextChangeEvent event) {
        String text = event.getText();
        setValue(text.toUpperCase());
    }
}


binder = new BeanFieldGroup<MyBean>(MyBean.class);
binder.setItemDataSource(ag);
Field<?> field = null;

Field field = binder.buildAndBind("Name", "name");
// Casting with TextUpper
TextUpper name = (TextUpper)binder.getField("name");
form.addComponent(name);
```

Any idea ???

Comment: What means "does not work"?

Comment: Yes, provide the specific failure message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess binder.getField() returns a TextField.
So after TextUpper name = (TextUpper)binder.getField("name"); it'll be still a TextField, you can check this by

```
name instanceof TextUpper
```

The cast does not change its type. You only say "I know this is a TextUpper, a special type of TextField", but it isn't, you only made it look like.
So if you do the cast and call methods afterwards, the object will still call the TextField's methods, and not the TextUpper ones.
You have to create a new TextUpper, set the the text (and other values) from the TextField and use this object if you want to have its behaviour.

Or, just use

```
buildAndBind(String caption,
                                        Object propertyId,
                                        Class<T> fieldType)
```

with TextUpper :)

https://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.alpha3/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/fieldgroup/FieldGroup.html#buildAndBind(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Class)

---

Try this:

```
 public TextUpper(Integer length){
        super();
        setMaxLength(length);   
        setImmediate(true);
        setTextChangeEventMode(TextChangeEventMode.EAGER);
        addTextChangeListener(this);
    }

    public TextUpper(){
        super(); 
        setImmediate(true);
        setTextChangeEventMode(TextChangeEventMode.EAGER);
        addTextChangeListener(this);
    }
```

I have the strong feeling that buildAndBind calls the parameter less constructor, as you do not put the parameter for length anywhere

Comment: I'm trying this: Field field = binder.buildAndBind("Name", "name", TextUpper.class); and still doesn't work.

Comment: What does not work and what do you expect? Did you tried to debug if all methods were called as you expect?

Comment: Can not check this at the moment, but you only do the work in the constructor with a parameter. Add the method calls to the parameter less constructor. Those are mostly called by default

Comment: Did you also put the initialisation stuff in the parameter-less constructor?

Comment: Tried the casting and doesn't work a CastingException is displayed. Tried use buildAndBind("Name", "name", TextUpper.class) and after I do the casting doesn't work also. Using instanceof return true to TextUpper but the text doesn't transform to uppercase.